# Visual Studio intellisense - display enum in numeric, not alpha order?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, enums

Let's say we have the following `enum`:

```
public enum Status
{
   New = 1,
   Acknowledged = 2,
   Approved = 3,
   Rejected = 4,
   Closed = 5
}
```

Intellisense will show them like:

```
Acknowledged
Approved
Closed
New
Rejected
```

Which, whilst useful to know, it would be more useful to have them in their original "numeric" order.

Is it possible to get Visual Studio's intellisense to do this?

Comment: Not with any out-of-the-box settings. *Maybe* possible if you write your own extension; not sure if there are IntelliSense hooks that allow you to preprocess the ordering. You might have to take over display entirely.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray - as I suspected. Obviously, "No" is a valid answer, even if there're any workarounds such as a numeric / alpha prefix, and I'll accept.

Comment: Well, the reason I didn't post it as an answer was that I wasn't sure. I mean, I'm confident that there are no out-of-the-box settings; I'm familiar enough with the features to know that for sure. But what I don't know is whether it is possible to do by writing your own extension, nor do I know if there are any extensions out there already (e.g., Resharper, Visual Assist X, etc.) that have this built in. So I figured I'd leave the question to see if someone else knows of a way.